# In Lua, how to find out what key an object is stored in

Tags: loops, indexing, lua, lua-table

Let's say I have.

```
local RockTable = {}
```

and then a for loop that creates 20 rocks and stores them in the RockTable.

How do I use the `table.remove(RockTable, ???)` to remove a specific rock that I want.

As I understand it when you remove an object from a table in Lua the rest of them shift forward changing the index count.

Hopefully I explained this well enough.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Each "rock" has an index, assuming you put them in the array part of the table, using either `table.insert` or `RockTable[#RockTable + 1]` or some similar syntax. Just pass that index to `table.remove`.

If you want to access "rocks" by name, then you don't put them into the array part of the table. The keys for them should not be integers; they should be strings or something else. Something named. To "remove" them, you simply set that value to `nil`.

```
--Setting the value:
RockTable["NameOfRock"] = rock;

--Removing the value:
RockTable["NameOfRock"] = nil;
```

Comment: If there's 3 rocks their index are 1,2,3. If I remove index 2 does the index of rock 3 change to 2 or does it stay at 3?

Comment: @Rico3D: Yes, it changes. That's why it's called the "array part of the table." You don't have empty elements in an array. If you want it to not act like an array, then you should stick a `nil` in there. But then, you won't get length and other array-like functions to work.

Comment: How would you `print()` out or find out the index of the rock? For example, if I spawned 20 random rocks on screen into the array part like this `RockTable[#RockTable + 1] = rock;`

How would I access the index? I tried `print(rock.index)` and it came out `nil`.

Apologize for my noobness, I've been googeling like crazy and came here after I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: @Rico3D: This is not a forum. This is a Q&A site. Your question was about storing objects in a table. This new question is a *new* question. So you should ask it using the "Ask Question" box.